# Extracting information with AWK and PATTERN

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file full of similar information to the section presented here:

```
 ***Message size:   100000 *** best  /  avg  / worst (MB/sec)
       task pair:    0 -    1:    7423.55 / 6960.54 / 46.69
       OVERALL AVERAGES:          7423.55 / 6960.54 / 46.69  
 ***Message size:    200000 *** best  /  avg  / worst (MB/sec)
       task pair:    0 -    1:    7423.55 / 6960.54 / 46.69
       OVERALL AVERAGES:          7423.55 / 6960.54 / 46.69
```

I want to extract determined information with `awk` related to a `Message size`, for instance if I want to extract the `avg`info from the `OVERALL AVERAGES` line  I would obtain:

```
100000   6960.54
200000   6960.54
```

I can easily get all `Message sizes` of the file or all `avg`

```
awk '/size:/  { print $3}' filename
awk '/size:/  {for(i=2; i<=2; i++) {getline;  print $8}}' filename
```

but I want to find a way of obtaining all that info together in a similar column fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this;

```
awk '/size:/  { printf $3};/OVERALL/  { print "\t" $5}'
```

Example;

```
user@host $ awk '/size:/  { printf $3};/OVERALL/  { print "\t" $5}' test
100000  6960.54
200000  6960.54
```

Comment: awesome! Nice and simple!

Answer (score 1):

Just put the message size into the variable `ms`:

```
awk '/***Message size:/{ms=$3} ms && /OVERALL AVERAGES:/{print ms,$5; ms=""}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

with some help from sed:

```
sed  -n '/ size:/{N;s/.* size: *\([0-9]*\)[^\n]*\n/\1/p}' input_file | \
     awk '{print $1, $9}'
```

Answer (score 1):

If Perl is an option:

```
perl -ane 'if (/size:/){print $F[2]} elsif(/OVERALL/){print "\t$F[4]\n"}' text
```

output:

```
100000  6960.54
200000  6960.54
```

These command-line options are used:

- `-n` loop around each line of the input file
- `-a` autosplit mode – split input lines into the `@F` array
- `-e` execute the perl code

`@F` is the array of words in each line, indexed starting with `$F[0]`
`$F[2]` is the third element in `@F`
`$F[4]` is the fifth element in `@F`